# I asked a question, but in retrospect it was the wrong one. What to do?

Tags: discussion, questions

I asked a question in which I ask the Silverstripe community with helping me out.  ([SilverStripe: Controller index is called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445223/silverstripe-controller-index-is-called-twice/))

I got help, but in the end the solution was on a completely different level than I anticipated when I first asked the question. There was no error in the script, it was a "feature" of Google Chrome.

Now I don't really know what to do with the question. I guess the final solution could still be useful, but the connection to Silverstripe is not there. I could change the question, but then the answers don't make any sense anymore, and could confuse readers. I could of course just remove the question, but the answer still has some merit (albeit as an anwer to a slightly different question)

Any idea what I could do best?

**Update**: The question is marked as a duplicate, but frankly I do not even understand why, as the linked duplicate is about someone who wants to change his question because he now wants to know why his own solution works, and it has no answers other than the one of the topic starter.

So the solution actually solves the question, but needs more elaboration. My 'solution', on the other hand was the observation that there was no problem with the code to begin with.

Comment: I think you handled it as best as you could.  You asked a question, provided feedback to the users who answers, and then posted the solution you found on your own as an answer.

Comment: Leave it the way it is, most questions are like this.  Point is that somebody else may well have the same mental hangup and will find your Q+A.

Comment: I agree, this isn't a duplicate - I can't find an "exact" duplicate, but I'm not sure that it matters. You've asked a question with a non-obvious answer and worked out the solution. Leave it alone and don't overthink this.